# Dynamic hyper link reference in Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

Can Doxygen build references such as a link is defined somewhere only once and any reference to it gets the corresponding redirection?
This would allow for `\see` commands pointing to the right resource without the need of duplicating the URL everywhere in the code, while making it easy to change said link if need be.

Generated docs would look a little bit like this:

**mainpage.md**

> #### Useful links are defined here
>
> [A guide to something](https://#)
>   [Datasheet of something](https://#)

**source.c File Reference**

> (...)
>   **See also**
>   [A guide to something](https://#)    //points to URL defined in mainfile.md

[**EDIT**]
Thanks to @albert in the comments, I've managed to do just that using `\snippetdoc`, however any text after the block-id makes doxygen unable to render the snippet.

Working example:
Knowing that my links are defined in the docs/mainpage.dox file like this:

```
[url_to_link1]
<a href="linkToSomething">Link description</a>
[url_to_link1]

[url_to_link2]
<a href="linkToSomething">Link description</a>
[url_to_link2]
```

This works:

```
/**
* \file
* \section links "Useful Links"
* - \snippetdoc docs/mainpage.dox url_to_link1
* - \snippetdoc docs/mainpage.dox url_to_link2
*/
```

This doesn't:

```
/**
* \file
* \brief     Some function definition
* \see       API reference on specific subject (more info: \snippetdoc docs/mainpage.dox url_to_link1)
*/
```

Doxygen version is 1.8.14

Comment: Did you have a look at the command ```\snippetdoc```, an alternative might be to define an ALIAS (in ```Doxyfile``` the doxygen configuration file) for the reference and use the defined command / alias on the required places.

Comment: Hi, thank you! Both options are valid, I'm using \snippetdoc it works just fine!

Comment: Actually there's one glitch with snippetdoc, if there's something after the block-id nothing gets printed. 

i.e:  
`(see @snippetdoc "docs/mainpage.dox" "freertos_api_url")` doesn't work  
`* - @snippetdoc docs/mainpage.dox freertos_api_url` works fine

Comment: Can you create a small example regarding these 2 situations? (as well as specifying the doxygen version you are using).

Comment: I've added examples in my question, by "doesn't work" I mean that doxygen blanks the whole thing, non-working example would print `API reference on specific subject (more info:`, even discarding the closing parenthesis in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the question and comments a solution for this problem lies in  the command `\snippetdoc`, an alternative is to define an `ALIAS` (in `Doxyfile` the doxygen configuration file) for the reference and use the defined command / alias on the required places.

As indicated by OP possible solutions by means of `\snippetdoc` are:

```
/**
* \file
* \section links "Useful Links"
* - \snippetdoc docs/mainpage.dox url_to_link1
* - \snippetdoc docs/mainpage.dox url_to_link2
*/
```

The following version does not work as indicated by OP:

```
/**
* \file
* \brief     Some function definition
* \see       API reference on specific subject (more info: \snippetdoc docs/mainpage.dox url_to_link1)
*/
```

The problem is that the definition of `\snippetdoc` is `\snippetdoc <file-name> ( block_id )` where `(block_id)` means that it reads till the end of the line (see the doxygen documentation) and thus the closing `)` is part of the `block_id` and cannot be resolved.

A possible better implementation could be `<block_id>` so that `block_id` is a single word. Problem for this is that this that it might break existing documentation where e.g. spaces or dots are used in the `block_id`.

There are a number of solutions for this problem:

1) Define the closing `)` as part of the `block_id` (in the not working version):

```
[url_to_link1)]
<a href="linkToSomething">Link description</a>)
[url_to_link1)]
```

2) Place the closing `)` on the next line (definition can stay as in the question):

```
/**
* \file
* \brief     Some function definition
* \see       API reference on specific subject (more info: \snippetdoc docs/mainpage.dox url_to_link1
*            )
*/
```

3) Define 2 definitions:

```
[url_to_link1)]
<a href="linkToSomething">Link description</a>)
[url_to_link1)]
[url_to_link1]
<a href="linkToSomething">Link description</a>
[url_to_link1]
```

I general solution 2) is the preferred solution as the solution. All text following the `block_id` has to be on the next line.